# Radio merging with label?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

I want After click on the radio,
Radio-selected that background color is yellow putting background lable, with use of css3?(If possible use of CSS, otherwise use of jQuery)

Example of myself: http://jsfiddle.net/DVJmS/8/
Example of ui: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/radio.html -> i not want use of plugin this is only a example.

With respect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd offer you the following, which seems to achieve your aims. Though I removed the styling from the input radios, just to simplify things a little (visually, at least):

```
$('input:radio').click(
    function(){
        $('label.checked').removeClass('checked');
        var labelFor = this.id;
        $('label[for="' + labelFor + '"]').addClass('checked');
    });
```

With the CSS:

```
label {
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
}
label.checked {
    background-color: #ffa;
    font-weight: bold;
}
input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DVJmS/10/).

Revised [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DVJmS/11/), just for a little added prettiness.

Comment: thanks, you may tell another example for the checkbox in JSFiddle?

Comment: Why after each click on the radio, it radio is not checked?

Comment: nice, I always thought <labels> were just a display element; I never knew their for attribute had linking functionality

Comment: @sheik: I thought the same thing, but the labels are linked to the radio button.  You can set the radio button to 'display:block' to see them trigger

Comment: @sheikhasa: I don't understand your question. After clicking the `label` text the radio input *is* checked. This can be seen by clicking the label text: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DVJmS/14/), and displaying the inputs themselves.